# switching dimensions in multicols environment

Tags: multicol

Is there an option to multicols environment so that the following piece of code

```latex
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

produces an output where *First* and *Second item* are on the first line, *Third* and *Fourth* on the second line?

Current piece of code produce *First* and *Third item* on the first line. Another way of asking it: is it possible to alter the environment behavior so that it *switches* rows and columns?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, multicol is for columns. Try tasks or hlist for horizontal lists.

Answer (score 2):

With the `paracol` package it is possible to switch columns.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}  
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First item \switchcolumn
        \item Second item \switchcolumn
        \item Third item  \switchcolumn
        \item Fourth item
    \end{itemize}   
\end{paracol}       

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `tasks`.

I use `twocolumn` just to make a smaller picture.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\kant[1][1-2]

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
\task First item
\task Second item
\task Third item
\task Fourth item
\end{tasks}

\kant[2][1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]